# unresolved referernce button

Tags: button, reference, android-viewbinding

Error in question unresolved reference :

[image]

as you can see in the screenshot, button has a red font,  alt enter doesn't fix it.

I think the problem might be view binding is not working for me on artic fox.   in the gradle file I have build type {
viewBinding true as you can see in the second screenshot. however button is still an unresolved reference :

[image]